# Order HTML elements on page alphabetically by ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that ajaxes in a list of images, then the success function of the ajax call opens the images as canvas backgrounds so the user can draw overlays on top.

Basically I have `for (key in data.imgs) { OpenImg(data.img[key]); }` calling this.  I need height & width in the OpenImg function so that I can specify the canvas size.

The trouble is I'm getting images out of order.  My img.onload function is necessary to delay the height/width detection until the image is loaded.

What I've figured out is that I need to wait for images to load, but also need to load them in succession  I can switch the canvas id assignment from a counter to a substring of the URL, which contains the page number.

The problem is even after renaming the canvas id's they won't change order on screen. Is there a good way to sort these? Could I just not append to the page, then later use JQuery .each() to place them, but how to make .each() run in order by id?

TL;DR: can I make this asynchronous function seem synchronous without it actually being synchronous?

```
function OpenImg(url) {
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=url;
    img.onload=function() {
        $('<div/>',{'id':'_wrap_pg'+canvasCount,'class':'wrapPage','Width':img.width,'Height':img.height,'data-w':img.width,'data-h':img.height,'data-url':url}).appendTo('#filebox');
        $('<canvas/>',{'id':'pg'+canvasCount,'Width':img.width,'Height':img.height,'data-w':img.width,'data-h':img.height,'data-url':url}).appendTo('#_wrap_pg'+canvasCount);
        var el=document.getElementById('pg'+canvasCount);
        if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager)!='undefined') G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(el);

        var date=new Date().getTime();  // use timestamp to force image not to cache
        $('#pg'+canvasCount).css({'background-image':'url('+url+'?t='+date+')',
            'filter':      "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+url+"', sizingMethod='scale')",
            '-ms-filter':  "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+url+"', sizingMethod='scale')"});

        InitDraw(canvasCount);  // function to attach events to newly created canvas
        if (canvasCount==1) {
            // if page 1 set zoom value to scale canvas/image to fit height
            $('#zoom').val(Math.floor(100/(img.height/$('#filebox').height()))-1);
        }
        zoom();  // my custom zoom function
        canvasCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and append the canvas to the page as part of the `OpenImg` function, *not* as part of the `onload` function. You can do the same for the `<div>`. Draw in a little "loading" icon or text too, so there's some feedback for the user. This will ensure that the elements are in the order they should be, regardless of loading order.

Comment: I already have loading feedback, not per image just the whole page (starts before the initial AJAX and finishes after all images have loaded). It's on a LAN so it doesn't take long. I was going to ask how I get the height/width before the image loads, but then realized I can place the elements first and resize inside the onload.  Now I feel dumb for asking lol.

Comment: Keep in mind that image dimensions is among the first piece of data in the image. I implement an auto-sizer on my site that polls using `setTimeout` until the dimensions are non-zero, rather than using `onload`, because that way it can size correctly ASAP then load the rest of the image.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would turn your object into an Array:

```
var arr = [];
for (key in data.imgs) { arr.push(data.img[key]); }
```

Then I would call your method:

```
OpenImg(arr, 0);
```

And your method would be:

```
function OpenImg(arr, index) {
    var img=new Image();
    img.src=arr[index];
    img.onload=function() {
        $('<div/>',{'id':'_wrap_pg'+index,'class':'wrapPage','Width':img.width,'Height':img.height,'data-w':img.width,'data-h':img.height,'data-url':url}).appendTo('#filebox');
        $('<canvas/>',{'id':'pg'+index,'Width':img.width,'Height':img.height,'data-w':img.width,'data-h':img.height,'data-url':url}).appendTo('#_wrap_pg'+index);
        var el=document.getElementById('pg'+index);
        if (typeof(G_vmlCanvasManager)!='undefined') G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(el);

        var date=new Date().getTime();  // use timestamp to force image not to cache
        $('#pg'+index).css({'background-image':'url('+url+'?t='+date+')',
            'filter':      "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+url+"', sizingMethod='scale')",
            '-ms-filter':  "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='"+url+"', sizingMethod='scale')"});

        InitDraw(index);  // function to attach events to newly created canvas
        if (index==1) {
            // if page 1 set zoom value to scale canvas/image to fit height
            $('#zoom').val(Math.floor(100/(img.height/$('#filebox').height()))-1);
        }
        zoom();  // my custom zoom function
        if (index < arr.length - 1)
            OpenImg(arr, ++index);
    }
}
```

I've changed all your "canvasCount" code to the Array's index, and it will only call the next OpenImg function when the last one has finished.